# UWP App: WebView: How to allow window.external.notify from within a app-local web page

Tags: uwp

For my UWP app, I would like to **allow the user to submit a search term from a web page stored in the app's `LocalState` folder into my UWP app**... So I am trying to use `WebView.ScriptNotify`.

The web page itself is stored in `ms-appx-web:///[SomeFolder]/[SomePage.html]`.
The WebView can open the page. It executes JavaScript.

When I try to call `window.external.notify`, the JS Engine gives me the error `TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'notify'`.

I have registered `ms-appx-web:///[SomeFolder]/*` as a Content URI in the app manifest and given it "Allow for web only" access, since the app has access to `Known Folders` (Documents, Photos etc)...

Where am I going wrong here???

App's Target Build is 17763.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide a minimum runnable demo to help me test it? I tried to create a new project and created a local html file. `window.external.notify` method can be accessed via `ms-appx-web` even without Content URIs

Comment: Actually, no. Takes too much time. The solution as described above works, and is actually better than going through Content URIs. windows.external.norify does NOT work through content URIs, two different methods. Closed.

Answer (score 0):

And of course there was a workaround. Never Mind ScriptNotify, the solution is a WindowsRuntimComponent... Here are two descriptions:

https://www.suchan.cz/2016/01/hacking-uwp-webview-part-2-bypassing-window-external-notify-whitelist/

http://blog.damiendelaire.com/2016/06/communicating-back-and-forth-with.html

Worked as described.